# Return 2 columns from MySQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm new in MySQL programing and I have one problem.
I created this query:

```
SELECT *,
       topics.createdate AS TopicCreateDate,
       (SELECT (SELECT username
                FROM   users
                WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid)
        FROM   topicanswers
        WHERE  topicid = topics.id
        ORDER  BY id DESC
        LIMIT  1)        AS LastPost
FROM   topics
       INNER JOIN categories
               ON topics.categoryid = categories.id
       INNER JOIN users
               ON topics.userid = users.id
ORDER  BY topics.lastupdate DESC
```

This query lists all `Topics`, joins categories and users by `UserID` and CategoryID in `Topics` and `Username` from `TopicAnswers` as `LastPost`. It orders them descending by `LastUpdate` in `Topics` that controlled by `TRIGER`.

It work pretty well, but there is a problem with this subquery:

```
            (SELECT (SELECT username
                    FROM   users
                    WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid)
            FROM   topicanswers
            WHERE  topicid = topics.id
            ORDER  BY id DESC
            LIMIT  1)        AS LastPost
```

It selects `Username`, of last post in topic, from `Users` by `UserID` from `TopicAnswers` as `LastPost`, now I want to select another one column from table `Users`, `AvatarURL`, but when I add :

```
                        (SELECT username, avatarurl
                        FROM   users
                        WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid)
```

It returns error:

> 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How I can slove this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is absolutely correct error, You are select single column in main select, so it must return only one column for avoid collisions

for each column make a new sub-select:

```
                (SELECT username
                FROM   users
                WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid) as username

                (SELECT avatarurl
                FROM   users
                WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid) as avatarur1
```

the same will be relate and to TOP level select:

```
   (SELECT (SELECT username
            FROM   users
            WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid)
```

**IF ADD SECOND QUERY THERE - it will throw an error for TOP Level SELECT**

```
FROM   topicanswers
WHERE  topicid = topics.id
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  1)        AS LastPost
```

You query should be like this :

```
SELECT *,
       topics.createdate AS TopicCreateDate,
       (SELECT (SELECT username
                FROM   users
                WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid)
        FROM   topicanswers
        WHERE  topicid = topics.id
        ORDER  BY id DESC
        LIMIT  1)        AS LastPost_name,

       (SELECT (SELECT avatarur1
                FROM   users
                WHERE  id = topicanswers.userid)
        FROM   topicanswers
        WHERE  topicid = topics.id
        ORDER  BY id DESC
        LIMIT  1)        AS LastPost_avatarur1

    FROM   topics
           INNER JOIN categories
                   ON topics.categoryid = categories.id
           INNER JOIN users
                   ON topics.userid = users.id
    ORDER  BY topics.lastupdate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you think about speed of this SQL query? Can I optimize it?

Comment: why You make ORDER  BY id DESC, if search also by id? so order of records not change and You can exclude this from query. I mean - when You search by ID, but order for example by DATE, than LIMIT 1 return last inserted ID .... but if ORDER BY still by ID - nothing change

Answer (score 2):

Another way to rewrite the query, without having 2 correlated inline subqueries is to have instead one `LEFT JOIN` in the `FROM` clause. The problem is that MySQL does not have `LATERAL` joins so it looks a bit clumsy and is quite confusing to get it right:

```
SELECT *,
       topics.createdate AS TopicCreateDate,
       lastpost_user.username  AS LastPost_UserName, 
       lastpost_user.avatarurl AS LastPost_AvatarURL
FROM   topics
       INNER JOIN categories
               ON topics.categoryid = categories.id
       INNER JOIN users
               ON topics.userid = users.id
       LEFT JOIN users AS lastpost_user
               ON lastpost_user.id = 
                   (SELECT userid 
                    FROM   topicanswers
                    WHERE  topicid = topics.id
                    ORDER  BY id DESC
                    LIMIT  1)
ORDER  BY topics.lastupdate DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to get what you need from something like

```
SELECT x.username, x.avatarurl,
       ...
FROM ...
JOIN ( SELECT username, avatarurl
           FROM   users
     ) AS x  ON  id = topicanswers.userid
```